# Quickly cross-check complex math results?

Tags: math, matlab

I am doing matrix operations on large matrices in my `C++` program. I need to verify the results that I get, I used to use `WolframAlpha` for the task up until now. But my inputs are very large now, and the web interface does NOT accept such large values (`textfield` is limited).

I am looking for a better solution to quickly cross-check/do math problems.

I know there is `Matlab` but I have never used it and I don't know if thats what will suffice my needs and how steep the learning curve would be?

Is this the time to make the jump? or there are other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using python, [numpy](https://numpy.org/) might be an option.

Apart from the license costs, MATLAB is the state of the art numerical math tool. There is [octave](https://octave.org/) as free open source alternative, with a similar syntax. The learning curve is for both tools absolutely smooth!

Comment: I'd go with octave first if you don't have access to MATLAB. (Think of it as a free trial without some of the bells and whistles.)

Answer (score 0):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) is web interface to [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica). The command syntax is exactly the same. If you have access to Mathematica at your university, it would be most smooth choice for you since you already have experience with WolframAlpha.

You may also try some packages to convert Mathematica commands to MATLAB:

- [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/)
- [Mathematica Symbolic Toolbox for MATLAB 2.0](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5344/)

---

Let us know in more details what is your validation process. How your data look like and what commands have you used in WolframALpha? Then we can help you with MATLAB alternative.